# VBA Copy and paste a single cell a defined number of times in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Ive got some VBA code that activates on the click of a button.
It copies and pastes values from a range of cells in one worksheet to a defined place in another worksheet.

However I would also like to copy a single cell of data from another place in the original sheet and have it copied into a defined no. of cells in that other worksheet. I have added the copy function to the bottom of a copy paste values function in the below code. But I am struggling with this as my code doesn't work. What is it I am doing wrong, please and how am I able to fix it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim controlRng, nRng As Range
Set controlRng = Range("AD12")  ' This the range of cells which I have defined to be my dropdown cells.
lastrow = Sheets("Planning").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If controlRng = "Apr-20" Then
    Range("AH10:AM30").Copy
    Sheets("Planning").Range("D" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Copy and paste values to next available rows in destination sheet
    Range("AB12").Copy
    Sheets("Planning").Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(14*("A2").Value
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with `Resize(14*("A2").Value`?

Comment: Yep,this is the code I found that would allow me to copy a single cell a defined amount of times, in this case copy the data in AB12 14 times starting in cell A2 of the other worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim controlRng, nRng As Range
    Set controlRng = Range("AD12")

    lastrow = Sheets("Planning").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If controlRng = "Apr-20" Then
        Range("AH10:AM30").Copy
        Sheets("Planning").Range("D" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Sheets("Planning").Range("A2").Resize(14, 1) = Range("AB12")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Typical I got my ranges the wrong way around.  I've another query about it, but i'll create another question for that. Thank you